# Not able to update DeletedAt column in loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update the delete column for all `AppGuid`  if `AppGuid` exists in database but not in the new payload (from API) update delete column with current date and time.

The statement `x.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;` is not hitting, I'm not able to define correct if condtion.

```cs
public async Task TestDeleteApps()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps?per_page=200");
    var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    AppsClass.AppsRootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppsClass.AppsRootobject>(json);
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

        foreach (var item in model.resources)
        {
            var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
            var x = _DBcontext.Apps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == g);

            if (x == null)
            {
                _DBcontext.Apps.Add(new Apps
                {
                    AppGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                    Name = item.name,
                    State = item.state,
                    CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                    UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                    SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.space.data.guid),
                    Foundation = 2,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                });
            }
            else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
            {
                x.State = item.state;
                x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                x.DeletedAt = null;
                x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else if (x.AppGuid.ToString() != item.guid)
            {
                x.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't sure either if you don't describe the issue you're seeing.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: it's not updating the database I'm not seeing any errors

Comment: And the line `x.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;` is being hit?

Comment: Nope it's not being hit thats the problem I'm not able to define correct `if condition `

Comment: The problem is `_DBcontext.Apps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == g)` either gives you`x` if it known, or null if it not known. So if `x` is unknown you create a new, which means that there will never be any that hit `x.AppGuid.ToString() != item.guid`.

Comment: Correct, the do I need to check again for the `AppGuid`? that's a another call to a database.

Comment: For the "deletion" part, you have to reverse the logic. All AppGuid in the database that is not part of your resource list should be set `DeletedAt = DateTime.Now`. So split you logic into two; `CreateOrUpdate` and a `Cleanup/Delete`.

Comment: Not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find those for "deletion" (`DeletedAt = DateTime.Now`) do this, in another method/process:

```
var guids = model.resources.Select( r => Guid.Parse(r.guid) );
var apps = _DBcontext.Apps.Where(o =>  guids.Contains(o.AppGuid) == false && o.Foundation == 2);
foreach( var app in apps )
{
    app.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
}
 await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: it updated the columns but it updated everything can I update only where `Foundation = 2`?

Comment: Updated answer, with `Foundation == 2` in where clause.